# Numpy array row indexing through an array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

Imagine I have the following (3,2) Numpy array A

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

and I would like to index this array A column-wise thanks to the indices available in numpy Array B :

```
B = np.array([[1,0],[2,0]])
```

So I would like to take rows 1 and 0 in column 0 and rows 2 and 0 in column 1 to obtain :

```
C = np.array([[3,1],[6,2]])
```

What is an efficient way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the column index with `np.arange(A.shape[1])`, transpose `B` so it broadcasts with the column index correctly, and then extract the elements with [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
A = np.array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

B = np.array([[1,0],[2,0]])

A[B.T, np.arange(A.shape[1])].T
#array([[3, 1],
#       [6, 2]])
```

Row index:

```
B.T
#           V second column row index
#array([[1, 2],
#       [0, 0]])
#        ^ first column row index
```

Column index:

```
np.arange(A.shape[1])
# array([0, 1])
```